# React native permission, IOS: Getting "blocked" permission when user "Don't allow" Microphone permission

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-permissions

I am using the package `react-native-permissions` and looking for the solution for the following problem

Use case:

1. On the prompt for permission for microphone for the first time, the user inputs `Don't Allow`
2. Once this is done the permission status is set to `blocked` and as per my research the user now need to manually go to the settings and allow microphone.
3. Upon permission change the app gets killed which I need to avoid

What should be the possible solution?

Is there a way the status can be set to `denied` instead of `blocked`, so that user can allow without leaving the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Unfortunately,once the user has selected "Don't Allow" for a permission request, the app cannot programmatically request the permission again without the user manually going to the device settings and granting the permission. This is a security feature implemented by the device operating system to prevent apps from repeatedly asking for permissions that the user has already denied.
2. react-native-permissions : [https://unpkg.com/browse/react-native-permissions@3.0.1/README.md#:~:text=%7C%20%60RESULTS.BLOCKED%60%20%7C%20The%20permission%20is%20denied%20and%20not%20requestable%20anymore%20%7C&text=Only%20%60Allow%20Once%60%2C%20%60Allow%20While%20Using%20App%60%20and%20%60Don't%20Allow%60](https://unpkg.com/browse/react-native-permissions@3.0.1/README.md#:%7E:text=%7C%20%60RESULTS.BLOCKED%60%20%7C%20The%20permission%20is%20denied%20and%20not%20requestable%20anymore%20%7C&text=Only%20%60Allow%20Once%60%2C%20%60Allow%20While%20Using%20App%60%20and%20%60Don%27t%20Allow%60)
3. Handling permissions in React Native : [https://hemanthkollanur.medium.com/handling-permissions-in-react-native-c4f29cf99e7a#:~:text=The%20permissions%20dialog%20shown%20by%20the%20system,might%20find%20that%20puzzling.%20It's%20a%20good%E2%80%A6](https://hemanthkollanur.medium.com/handling-permissions-in-react-native-c4f29cf99e7a#:%7E:text=The%20permissions%20dialog%20shown%20by%20the%20system,might%20find%20that%20puzzling.%20It%27s%20a%20good%E2%80%A6)
4. React Native: Managing App Permissions for iOS : https://rossbulat.medium.com/react-native-managing-app-permissions-for-ios-4204e2286598
5. react-native-permissions : https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions

   ```
   import * as permissions from 'react-native-permissions';

   const checkMicrophonePermission = async () => {
     const result = await permissions.check(permissions.PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.RECORD_AUDIO);

     if (result === 'denied') 
     {
       alert('Microphone permission has been denied. Please go to your device settings and grant the permission manually.');
     }
   };


   // Call the function to check the permission status
   checkMicrophonePermission();
   ```